# Where do the electrons come from in DC generator

Tags: electricity, electrons, electric-current

I understand that electrons are not created nor destroyed. In AC voltage the electrons are oscilating back and forth in material. But I cannot understand where do the electrons come from that are created by DC generator. Because by DC generator the electrons in the conductor flow only in one direction, logicaly they have to be somewhere lost and created. What Am I missing?

Comment: They "exit" the generator in one end and "enter" it in the other. Remember that a current only will flow in a complete circuit

Answer (score 3):

A DC generator acts like a pump that pushes electrons round the circuit. Electrons go out from the negative terminal of the generator and flow into the positive terminal forming a closed loop, nothing gets created nor destroyed.

Comment: Ok. And what if is part of the circuit a capacitor. I apply DC voltage for 5 minutes. The capacitor charged up with electrons and then I disconect the circuit. I have loaded capacitor with electrons and these electrons are now missing in circuit. Or not?

Comment: @trenccan The total charge on the capacitor is zero, the positive charge on one plate is exactly equal to the negative charge on the other. Now you can say you removed one plate only and kept the other connected, but that's an independent issue... The point is that a DC generator only pumps electrons across the circuit and doesn't create them, the same way your heart pumps blood across your veins and doesn't actually create blood.

Answer (score -1):

Electrons are not lost or stored or anything, I believe electricity is only the moving or path of the electron, so they are probably moving back on the other end of your circuit, the electrons arent lost or "burned" like fuel they're just moving in a direction